# Error passing an UnsafeMutablePointer to a function

Tags: objective-c, c, swift, unsafemutablepointer

i am an ios developer who uses swift.
I am using an sdk in order to communicate with an ip camera retrieve data from it, and show it to the user. 
I ve a project shipped with the sdk, which is written in obj c, and is working without problems. The problem is i am not able to pass the parameter to the expected parameter type from the function.
The SDK is very old, i integrated it using static libraries and a bridging header and i was able to connect successfully to the camera. I think the sdk is written in c or c++, and i am basically having problems with the parameter conversion.

**Fos.h**

```
typedef struct   
{ 
int                       channel;
long long                 time;
unsigned int              index;
FOSMEDIATYPE              type;     //Is video or audio
FOSDECFMT                 fmt;      //The format of video or audio.
short                     isKey;
short                     multiAudioPage;
int                       frameTag; 
union{ 
    FOSVIDEO_INFO      video;       //Media type is video.
    FOSAUDIO_INFO      audio;       //Media type is audio.
} media;
unsigned long long      pts;        //Pts.
unsigned int              len;      //Size of data.
char                      data[0];  //Just data.
}ATTRIBUTE_PACKED FOSDEC_DATA;    //Save the video or audio data,include video or audio information.
```

.

**Objective C function, currently working**

```
- (IBAction)login:(id)sender {
//[self._imageView add]
NSString* str = [self._textField text];
const char* url = [str UTF8String];
char ip[128];
int port;
char usr[64];
char pwd[64];
int count = sscanf(url, "%[^:]:%d/%[^:]:%s", ip, &port, usr, pwd);
if (count != 4) {
    return;
}

mHandle = FosSdk_Create(ip, "", usr, pwd, port, port, FOSIPC_H264, FOSCNTYPE_IP);
//mHandle = FosSdk_Create(ip, "FASDFDSAFDASFASD", usr, pwd, port, port, FOSIPC_H264, FOSCNTYPE_P2P);
if (mHandle == FOSHANDLE_INVALID) {
    return;
}
[self._Login setEnabled:NO];
[self._Logout setEnabled:YES];

[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(RunInThread:) toTarget:self withObject:^(void *param){

    int usrPrivilege = 0;
    FOSCMD_RESULT ret = FosSdk_Login(mHandle, &usrPrivilege, 500);
    if (FOSCMDRET_OK != ret) {
        return;
    }

    ret = FosSdk_OpenVideo(mHandle, FOSSTREAM_SUB, 500);
    if (FOSCMDRET_OK != ret) {
        return;
    }
    //char* framebuf = (char*)malloc(512*1024);
    FOSDEC_DATA* data = NULL;

    int outlen = 0;
    while (mHandle) {
// FosSdk_RetainHandle(mHandle, &usrPrivilege);
        if ( FOSCMDRET_OK == FosSdk_GetVideoData(mHandle, (char**)&data, &outlen, FOSDECTYPE_RGB24) && outlen>0)
        {

            if (data->type == FOSMEDIATYPE_VIDEO) {
                //int a=0;
                //a++;
                [self imageFromAVPicture:data->data width:data->media.video.picWidth height:data->media.video.picHeight];
            }
            else{
            }
        }
        usleep(20*1000);
    }
 }];
}
```

.

**The method signature in fos.h**

```
    FOSSDK FOSCMD_RESULT FOSAPI FosSdk_GetVideoData(FOSHANDLE handle, char **data, int *outLen, FOSDECFMT videoFmt);
```

.

**When calling it from objective-c**

```
FosSdk_GetVideoData(<#unsigned int handle#>, <#char **data#>, <#int *outLen#>, <#FOSDECFMT videoFmt#>)
}];
```

.

**When calling it from swift**

```
FosSdk_GetVideoData(handle: UInt32,
                   data: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?>!,
                   outLen: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>!,
                   videoFmt: FOSDECFMT)
```

.

**The error is data parameter, exactly:**

```
Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<FOSDEC_DATA>' to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?'
```

.

**I ve tried changing the declaration of data to this, but it gives me this error**

```
let data = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>(&fosdecData)
Ambiguous use of 'init'
```

.

This pointer stuff is a bit complicated but i was able to pair my device with the camera, using methods which used unsafeMutablePointers too.
However, i cannot figure out how to pass this empy data object to the function.

The SDK is outdated and bad documented, which does not help.
Anyway, i need to make it working.
Hope to get some help, thanks coders!
.

**EDIT, THANKS TO OOPer**
.
Here is the updated version in swift, which actually produces an unexpected error. The result returned from the function is now 0, so it s correct. However, trying to access original FosdedData struct, i have a **Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11**.
How could i solve this? Sorry for long question, i wanted to be accurate.

```
var mhandle : UInt32 = FOS_HANDLE_INIT.rawValue

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //These functions basically do camera pairing, and write result on mhandle, which is equal to 0 , if functions work, otherwise 1
    initializeFOS()
    startEzLinkFOS()
    sdkCreateFOS()
    loginFOS()
    openVideoFOS()        

    var data: UnsafeMutablePointer<FOSDEC_DATA>? = nil
    var outlen : Int32 = 0
    while self.mhandle > 0 {
        let resultOOPer = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &data) { pointerToFosdecData in
            pointerToFosdecData.withMemoryRebound(to: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?.self, capacity: 1, { (pointerToInt8Pointer) in

                FosSdk_GetVideoData(self.mhandle, pointerToInt8Pointer, &outlen, FOSDECTYPE_RGB24)
            })
        }

        if resultOOPer == FOSCMDRET_OK && outlen > 0{
            if let unwrData = data {

                //if unwrData.pointee.type == FOSMEDIATYPE_VIDEO{
                //Produced Output when i try access pointee, which is actually the fosdecData struct i need:
                //Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11
                //}
            }
        }
        usleep(20*1000)
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, using the initializer of `UnsafeMutablePointer` in this way may generate an unexpected result and you should never do:

```
let data = UnsafeMutablePointer<FOSDEC_DATA>(&fosdecData)
```

Swift compiler may prepare a temporary region for the inout parameter and pass the address of the region, which is released immediately after the call. Unfortunately, this code may work in some cases, but you know codes work-in-some-cases can be a hard-to-fix bug.

---

Second, in your Objective-C code, you **declare `data` as `FOSDEC_DATA*` -- pointer to `FOSDEC_DATA` -- and initializing it to `NULL`**.

Why are you trying to initialize your Swift version of `data` with `&fosdecData`? There's no `fosdecData` in your Objective-C code.

The equivalent Swift code for the declaration of `data` should be like this:

```
var data: UnsafeMutablePointer<FOSDEC_DATA>? = nil
```

You should **declare `data` as `UnsafeMutablePointer<FOSDEC_DATA>?` -- pointer to `FOSDEC_DATA` -- and initialize it to `nil`**.

In addition, it needs to be `var`, your `FosSdk_GetVideoData` would rewrite it to a valid pointer to `FOSDEC_DATA`.

---

Third, you need to pass `UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?>!` to the second parameter of `FosSdk_GetVideoData`, but `&data` would generate a pointer of type `UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<FOSDEC_DATA>?>`.

To make this sort of pointer type conversion, you need to use `withMemoryRebound<T, Result>(to:capacity:_:)`. And you need to call `withUnsafeMutablePointer<T, Result>(to:_:)` to get a pointer to `data`.

```
let result = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &data) {
    pointerToFosdecDataPtr in
    //pointerToFosdecDataPtr: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<FOSDEC_DATA>?>
    pointerToFosdecDataPtr.withMemoryRebound(to: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?.self, capacity: 1) {
        pointerToInt8Ptr in
        //pointerToInt8Ptr: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?>
        //...
    }
}
```

---

So, your Swift code equivalent to your Objective-C code would be something like this:

```
var data: UnsafeMutablePointer<FOSDEC_DATA>? = nil
var outlen: Int32 = 0

while mHandle != 0 {

    let result = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &data) {
        pointerToFosdecDataPtr in
        //pointerToFosdecDataPtr: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<FOSDEC_DATA>?>
        pointerToFosdecDataPtr.withMemoryRebound(to: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?.self, capacity: 1) {
            pointerToInt8Ptr in
            //pointerToInt8Ptr: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?>
            FosSdk_GetVideoData(mHandle, pointerToInt8Ptr, &outlen, FOSDECTYPE_RGB24)
            //Implicit `return` works here and the result is passed to `result`.
        }
    }
    if result == FOSCMDRET_OK && outlen > 0 {
        if let data = data, data.pointee.type == FOSMEDIATYPE_VIDEO {
            //...
            //self.imageFromAVPicture...
        } else {
        }
    }
    usleep(20*1000)
}
```

---

**EDIT**

Code updated to reflect whole behavior of the **currently working** Objective-C code. (Renamed `mhandle` to `mHandle` as in Objective-C code.)

Comment: Thank you very much OOPer, this code makes the compiler happy, but however, the result is 1, which is negative in this case.So the function is giving back an error.
. 
**Also, i noticed** data property is nil, and trying to access data.pointee gives me the error **Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11**

Comment: Thanks for reporting. But my code above, `let result = ...; if result == FOSCMDRET_OK {...}` would output machine codes equivalent to your ObjC code `if ( FOSCMDRET_OK == ...) {...}`. Have you filled up all code equivalent to your ObjC code? For example, my code omitted `while (mHandle) {...}` as you have not referred to that part in your question. But, in fact, you need it. And generally, when the result of an API call returned non-OK value, the API does not affect the region specified by pointer arguments. So, if it returned `1` and it's not OK, it's quite natural `data` is still `nil`.

Comment: You are not showing how `mHandle` is declared nor is given a value. If you get non-OK result with my Swift code, that's because other parts of your Swift code is wrong. Do not hide relevant parts of your code and show all of them.

Comment: I am sorry if i ommitted relevant code. Would the objective c function implementation (file .h and .m ) and .swift class where i am actually working, be enough? I could also send you the project if you would want to take a look, its not a problem, and is a project i created only for camera implementation, so its pretty basic. Thanks for all your help,here is a preview 
https://paste.ofcode.org/37dqy55aSbci868attH7qi3

Comment: @Simone, I have updated the last code in my answer, which is equivalent to your **currently working** Objective-C code. That's all I can do as for now. If you need more, you should include more info (not too much more than enough) into your question. There may be many others who can solve your issue, with including such info in the question, they can answer it without reading long comments.

Comment: @Simone, why do you put `DispatchQueue.main.async` in your updated code? You have not shown any of `dispatch_queue` in your **currently working** ObjC code. I cannot say anything about codes which are not included in your question.

Comment: because, from my code interpretation, the line 
**[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(RunInThread:) toTarget:self withObject:^(void *param){** in objective c, should be something related to threads, so thats why i ve put a dispatch async. Please note that even without the dispatch, **every** time i access data.pointee, compiler complains about segmentation error. It looks impossible to solve...

Comment: @Simone, first, include that part (or a little more) into your question. Second, `detachNewThreadSelector:oTarget:withObject:` is completely different thing than `DispatchQueue.main.async`. Third, **Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11** is caused by a compiler bug, usually triggered by some combinations of errors in your code. Anyway, I have given up to help you, as you are ignoring my repeated request to update your ObjC code. I cannot help who do not want to be helped. Hope someone can help you or you can fix the issue by yourself. Good luck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150374/discussion-between-simone-and-ooper).

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?